# Empty value output from string array

Tags: c#, arrays

I practice with C# Console Application. I have little problem with no value output from string array, when I insert a value from typing on console application then and there are no display from `favorite = { food }`.
let me show you simple code lines, see below:

```
string food = "";
string[] favorite = { food };

Console.WriteLine("what is your favorite food?");
food = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Your favorite food is"+favorite[0]);
```

Comment: `favourite[0] = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: `string[] favourite = { food };` What this is doing is storing the value of `food` **at the time** in to the array. So move that line of code **after** assigning to `food` (not before). And everything will work fine. I mean, it is weird you are using an array at all - but the change I am suggesting will make things work.

Comment: I move string[] favourite = { food }; to underline of food = Console.ReadLine(); and success to display on console applicaton. thannk you Mjwills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect 5 favorite foods

```cs
string[] favourite = new string[5];

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"what is your #{i} favourite food?");
    favourite[i - 1] = Console.ReadLine();
}


Console.WriteLine("Here are your top foods --");
foreach(string f in favourite)
    Console.WriteLine($"--- {f}");
```

Comment: @ChrisVanGewden if the answer brought you closer to understanding how to use arrays please use buttons to upvote and accept the answer. Questions without accepted answers don't help much

Comment: I tried upvote for you and Mijwills but, Stackoverflow's website said **"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."**. I expect to get over 15 Reputation, the I will upvote to anyone.

Comment: @ChrisVanGewden Don't worry. I gave you some :-)

Comment: thank you lots for help